# Vagrant can't access web server on guest machine from host machine browser

Tags: apache, vagrant

I am trying to access the web server inside my Vagrant machine from my host OS browser at localhost:8080, though I only get a 404 Not Found error.

Here are Vagrantfile, bootstrap.sh, and log file after running vagrant up

Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

    config.vm.box = "Ubuntu14.04"
    config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080,
        auto_correct: true
end
```

bootstrap.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

apt-get update
apt-get install -y apache2
if ! [ -L /var/www ]; then
rm -rf /var/www
ln -fs /vagrant /var/www
```

output from $vagrant up

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'Ubuntu14.04'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: semioleague_default_1443295419374_21654
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 => 8080 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: 
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default: 
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
No installation found.
stdin: is not a tty
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Suggested packages:
  debhelper
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dkms
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic
1 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 151 not upgraded.
Need to get 772 kB of archives.
After this operation, 349 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main dkms all 2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic amd64 3.13.0-24.47 [708 kB]
Fetched 708 kB in 3s (193 kB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
stdin: is not a tty
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg [933 B]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg [933 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release [63.5 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release [63.5 kB]
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg [933 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release [63.5 kB]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources [96.1 kB]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [236 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources [2,061 B]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources [31.1 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [4,725 B]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [138 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [5,144 B]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources [2,341 B]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [622 kB]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages [344 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [15.4 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [319 kB]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [11.9 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [603 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [15.1 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [320 kB]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [12.1 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en [301 kB]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en [3,560 B]
Get:26 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages [8,875 B]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en [168 kB]
Get:28 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages [117 kB]
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources [5,860 B]
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources [28 B]
Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources [28.4 kB]
Get:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources [1,898 B]
Get:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages [6,288 B]
Get:34 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [3,691 B]
Get:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages [28 B]
Get:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages [32.6 kB]
Get:37 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages [329 kB]
Get:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages [1,571 B]
Get:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages [6,293 B]
Get:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages [28 B]
Get:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages [32.6 kB]
Get:42 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages [1,552 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en
Get:43 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages [8,846 B]
Get:44 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages [117 kB]
Get:45 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages [3,833 B]
Get:46 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en [188 kB]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US
Get:47 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en [68.2 kB]
Fetched 4,404 kB in 5s (751 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
stdin: is not a tty
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Suggested packages:
  debhelper
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dkms
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic
1 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 168 not upgraded.
Need to get 65.4 kB/773 kB of archives.
After this operation, 351 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main dkms all 2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.2 [65.4 kB]
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: No such file or directory
Fetched 65.4 kB in 0s (128 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package dkms.
(Reading database ... 59192 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic_3.13.0-24.47_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic (3.13.0-24.47) over (3.13.0-24.46) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Setting up dkms (2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.2) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic (3.13.0-24.47) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 3.13.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
Copy iso file /usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso into the box /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
stdin: is not a tty
mount: block device /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso is write-protected, mounting read-only
Installing Virtualbox Guest Additions 5.0.4 - guest version is 
stdin: is not a tty
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 5.0.4 Guest Additions for Linux............
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ...
Removing existing VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Removing existing VirtualBox non-DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel modules ...done.
Doing non-kernel setup of the Guest Additions ...done.
Starting the VirtualBox Guest Additions ...done.
Installing the Window System drivers
Could not find the X.Org or XFree86 Window System, skipping.
An error occurred during installation of VirtualBox Guest Additions 5.0.4. Some functionality may not work as intended.
In most cases it is OK that the "Window System drivers" installation failed.
stdin: is not a tty
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /home/kirtis/_projects/vagrant_boxes/semioleague
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: /tmp/vagrant-shell20150926-21374-vvdd3f.sh
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
==> default: Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
==> default: Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release
==> default: Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources
==> default: Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources
==> default: Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources
==> default: Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
==> default: Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources
==> default: Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
==> default: Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
==> default: Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages
==> default: Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages
==> default: Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
==> default: Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease
==> default: Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages
==> default: Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
==> default: Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en
==> default: Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
==> default: Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US
==> default: Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
==> default: Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US
==> default: Reading package lists...
==> default: Reading package lists...
==> default: Building dependency tree...
==> default: Reading state information...
==> default: The following extra packages will be installed:
==> default:   apache2-bin apache2-data libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
==> default:   libaprutil1-ldap ssl-cert
==> default: Suggested packages:
==> default:   www-browser apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine apache2-suexec-custom
==> default:   apache2-utils openssl-blacklist
==> default: The following NEW packages will be installed:
==> default:   apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
==> default:   libaprutil1-ldap ssl-cert
==> default: 0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 168 not upgraded.
==> default: Need to get 1,286 kB of archives.
==> default: After this operation, 5,348 kB of additional disk space will be used.
==> default: Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libapr1 amd64 1.5.0-1 [85.1 kB]
==> default: Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libaprutil1 amd64 1.5.3-1 [76.4 kB]
==> default: Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 amd64 1.5.3-1 [10.5 kB]
==> default: Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libaprutil1-ldap amd64 1.5.3-1 [8,634 B]
==> default: Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main apache2-bin amd64 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.6 [841 kB]
==> default: Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main apache2-data all 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.6 [160 kB]
==> default: Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main apache2 amd64 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.6 [87.6 kB]
==> default: Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main ssl-cert all 1.0.33 [16.6 kB]
==> default: dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: No such file or directory
==> default: Fetched 1,286 kB in 5s (223 kB/s)
==> default: Selecting previously unselected package libapr1:amd64.
==> default: (Reading database ... 59240 files and directories currently installed.)
==> default: Preparing to unpack .../libapr1_1.5.0-1_amd64.deb ...
==> default: Unpacking libapr1:amd64 (1.5.0-1) ...
==> default: Selecting previously unselected package libaprutil1:amd64.
==> default: Preparing to unpack .../libaprutil1_1.5.3-1_amd64.deb ...
==> default: Unpacking libaprutil1:amd64 (1.5.3-1) ...
==> default: Selecting previously unselected package libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3:amd64.
==> default: Preparing to unpack .../libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3_1.5.3-1_amd64.deb ...
==> default: Unpacking libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3:amd64 (1.5.3-1) ...
==> default: Selecting previously unselected package libaprutil1-ldap:amd64.
==> default: Preparing to unpack .../libaprutil1-ldap_1.5.3-1_amd64.deb ...
==> default: Unpacking libaprutil1-ldap:amd64 (1.5.3-1) ...
==> default: Selecting previously unselected package apache2-bin.
==> default: Preparing to unpack .../apache2-bin_2.4.7-1ubuntu4.6_amd64.deb ...
==> default: Unpacking apache2-bin (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.6) ...
==> default: Selecting previously unselected package apache2-data.
==> default: Preparing to unpack .../apache2-data_2.4.7-1ubuntu4.6_all.deb ...
==> default: Unpacking apache2-data (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.6) ...
==> default: Selecting previously unselected package apache2.
==> default: Preparing to unpack .../apache2_2.4.7-1ubuntu4.6_amd64.deb ...
==> default: Unpacking apache2 (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.6) ...
==> default: Selecting previously unselected package ssl-cert.
==> default: Preparing to unpack .../ssl-cert_1.0.33_all.deb ...
==> default: Unpacking ssl-cert (1.0.33) ...
==> default: Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
==> default: Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
==> default: ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
==> default: Processing triggers for ufw (0.34~rc-0ubuntu2) ...
==> default: Setting up libapr1:amd64 (1.5.0-1) ...
==> default: Setting up libaprutil1:amd64 (1.5.3-1) ...
==> default: Setting up libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3:amd64 (1.5.3-1) ...
==> default: Setting up libaprutil1-ldap:amd64 (1.5.3-1) ...
==> default: Setting up apache2-bin (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.6) ...
==> default: Setting up apache2-data (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.6) ...
==> default: Setting up apache2 (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.6) ...
==> default: Enabling module mpm_event.
==> default: Enabling module authz_core.
==> default: Enabling module authz_host.
==> default: Enabling module authn_core.
==> default: Enabling module auth_basic.
==> default: Enabling module access_compat.
==> default: Enabling module authn_file.
==> default: Enabling module authz_user.
==> default: Enabling module alias.
==> default: Enabling module dir.
==> default: Enabling module autoindex.
==> default: Enabling module env.
==> default: Enabling module mime.
==> default: Enabling module negotiation.
==> default: Enabling module setenvif.
==> default: Enabling module filter.
==> default: Enabling module deflate.
==> default: Enabling module status.
==> default: Enabling conf charset.
==> default: Enabling conf localized-error-pages.
==> default: Enabling conf other-vhosts-access-log.
==> default: Enabling conf security.
==> default: Enabling conf serve-cgi-bin.
==> default: Enabling site 000-default.
==> default:  * Starting web server apache2
==> default:  * 
==> default: Setting up ssl-cert (1.0.33) ...
==> default: Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6) ...
==> default: Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
==> default: Processing triggers for ufw (0.34~rc-0ubuntu2) ...
```

What am I doing wrong? I've followed the instructions exactly from the website with the exception of using a different box. I am able to ssh into the box and everything seems to be correct. Please inform me if there is any more information needed.

Comment: Still not sure what the issue may have been. Possible networking conflicts with VM's not destroying in Virtualbox.

Removed all VM instances and created a new Vagrant VM without bootstraping Apache and instead installed it manually through vagrant ssh and now I'm able to access the web server in vagrant.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I met the problem like that, I posted the way to resolve it at https://stackoverflow.com/a/32846069/4988779. Good luck.